# How to get data from mySQL database and render a graph from it

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, graph

I have a User dashboard on my site where users can log into and view certain things. one of the things i want them to be able to see is a Graphical representation of certain data relating to them in a database.

My database contains two basic columns. Actual Time and Target Time. I then need to create a bar graph showing actual times against target times to give a visual representation of the two.

I currently have the following jScript framework for a bar graph and would like my data to be displayed into this:

```
/*
 * charts/chart_bars_vertical.js
 *
 * Demo JavaScript used on charts-page for "Vertical Bars".
 */

"use strict";

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Sample Data
    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i += 1)
        d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);



    var d2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i += 1)
        d2.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

    var d3 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i += 1)
        d3.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

    var ds = new Array();

    ds.push({
        label: "Bar #1",
        data: d1,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.2,
            order: 1
        }
    });
    ds.push({
        label: "Bar #2",
        data: d2,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.2,
            order: 2
        }
    });
    ds.push({
        label: "Bar #3",
        data: d3,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.2,
            order: 3
        }
    });

    // Initialize Chart
    $.plot("#chart_bars_vertical", ds, $.extend(true, {}, Plugins.getFlotDefaults(), {
        series: {
            lines: { show: false },
            points: { show: false }
        },
        grid:{
            hoverable: true
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: '%s: %y'
        }
    }));

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: google charts has great support, i used it successfuly without actually knowing php or js.
http://datamakessense.com/google-charts-api-from-your-sql-database-to-a-live-chart-with-no-coding-skills/#sthash.jiQxRS87.dpbs

Comment: Never did thank you for your recommendation! Sure aren't as flashy as the jScript charts what came with my off the shelf dashboard but a very easy to use API. I've been using google charts for the past 4 months & my customers love it. Many thanks.

Comment: myself i find them nice to use, and even the deprecated image charts can be incredibly useful - on the same site you find an example of a html daily stats email with those. They sure do make life easy :)